# Android WebView: zoom to a specific scale after content is loaded

Tags: android, webview, zooming

How to zoom WebView's content to a specific scale after the content is loaded? (I don't want to reload the content.)

I'm working on Android 2.3 and later.

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1: Here we set zoom level by percentage this meaning that when the page is ready getScale will return 5.2f:

```
mView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        view.setInitialScale(520);

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
```

Solution 2: This approach isn't 100% accurate because it rounds the scale to int value:

```
private WebView mView;
private Handler mZoomHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mZoomRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if ((int) mView.getScale() < WANTED_SCALE) {
            mView.zoomIn();
            mZoomHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        } else if ((int) mView.getScale() > WANTED_SCALE) {
            mView.zoomOut();
            mZoomHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    }
};

mView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mZoomRunnable.run();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, please give me some time to test if this works well enough for my need and I will report back

Comment: Sorry this did not work. The `run()` runs on forever as `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` have a too large zoom level that it can never reach `WANTED_SCALE`.

Comment: This worked ok with Nexus 5 running 4.4 platform. Which device are you using ?

Comment: Which scale level you are wanting to get and which is the start when onPageFinished get's called first time?

Comment: By saying that run() is called forever, can you see any changes in the zoom level? Did you try giving more delay for Handler than 10ms?

Comment: @Niko: We run it on Nexus 7 and 4.4 platform, too. But the webview has became looping with zoom out and zoom in forever. 
I've tried with WANTED_SCALE=1.6d, and the initial scale of webview at first time is set at 1.
I think the Zoomout & zoomin will only jump to pre-define scale-level, so in this case it simply just can not reach the scale of 1.6

Comment: Okay the never ending loop could be caused here, because it probably scales integer value, not float, so it jumps to 2 then back to 1 and so on. In this case you want to zoom to float value, not sure if its possible. Working with WebView is painful, because the API is so limited and hidden, so can't really get any sources to check if you could invoke some private method there.

Comment: I will dig this through today to find out if there is any way you can get it zoomed to float value I will be posting my findings on my answer.

Comment: @Niko yes I think that is the problem: I cannot seem to set zoom level to a float value.

Comment: Sorry Its still not working, Niko.
I've tested it on Nexus 7 and log out the scale change. 
Initial scale set at 520, WANTED_SCALE = 6.7f (first time test it is set at 1.6f), in both case it's just didn't work at all. 
Looked at the log result, webview zoom scale always changed between 1.331 and 6.656 and never reach 6.7.

Comment: Platform: Nexus 7 Android 4.4

Comment: Oh you understood it wrong, just use the view.setInitialScale(160), the other solution is not needed when you use only that.

Comment: @Niko I see. `setInitialScale` works well for Android 4.4: you can change the zoom level after page has loaded. But for Android 2.3, `setInitialScale` only works when page first loads -- after the page has loaded, `setInitialScale` cannot change the zoom level anymore. This is where I'm stuck: a way to change zoom level of Android 2.3 Webview.

Comment: For older platform you will have to use the second solution and accept that it cannot support float zoom values. Sometimes you have to make compromises when dealing with such variety of platforms and all the devices which can deal same code different way :(

Comment: I see. Guess I have to accept that for now. I will try to find a better way out and report back if I find anything. Thanks a lot for your support.